Closing and suggesting other sites within SE network (not SO)
At times I close vote a question because it belongs on another site within the SE network. Most of the time it belongs on SO and there's a default entry in the menu under offtopic -> question on SW dev belong at SO. 
However sometimes it belongs on the crypto or unix (or another one) sites. Looking at the close voting menu I see just 2 options. 

Offtopic because -> Question belongs on another site in the SE network -> belongs on meta.reverseengineering.com
Offtopic because -> Other -> <your own comment>

The first choice, although sounding like the right one, only gives me 1 option to choose from. I don't see how I add custom menu entry there. This leaves only the second option and writing a custom message. 
What is the right/preferred way of close voting while suggesting other sites within the SE network?

If there is no option for users with closing privileges to migrate a question to specific site, the way to get a question migrated to some site is to flag this question for moderator attention with "Other" flag ("This question belongs to {site}, because...") - you are right about your second option. Moderators will have an ability to migrate this question.
Your flag, however, can be declined if the moderator who reviewed it felt inappropriate to migrate this question.
Another way would be to raise a meta-question to discuss if the question you want to be migrated is really off-topic there (moderators will see your question most likely).
And please don't request migration / migrate of crap.
